# Run only assembly:single goal without error

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

When I try to run only assembly:single after a full build,

```
mvn -DskipTests -DskipAssembly=true assembly:single
```

I get the following error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.1.0:single
> (default-cli) on project assemble: Failed to create assembly:
> Artifact: my.package:mymodule:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (included by module)
> does not have an artifact with a file. Please ensure the package phase
> is run before the assembly is generated.

I'm not running clean in between; so, I would expect that everything needed to make the assembly is still where it's supposed to be. In addition, I can look in my local repository and see that mymodule is there. I have the following configuration on project assemble. The **skipAssembly** part is so that the assembly plugin doesn't doesn't run on the other modules.

```
<configuration>
    <skipAssembly>false</skipAssembly>
    <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
</configuration>
```

The reason I'm trying to run assembly:single separately is because I'm using an incremental module builder, which throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException on one of about two dozen modules during compile. I can live with the one module not being rebuilt, and I can use
**-Dmaven.compiler.failOnError=false** to ensure the rest of the modules build, but the assembly plugin never runs.

Comment: I am not sure, but this may be the same situation as with the maven deploy plugin: The generated artifacts are attached to the running build and this information is evaluated. So if you have a separate Maven run, the information is gone.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Is there a way I can test your theory?